# .NET Core unable to load .NET Standard class library with dependencies

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

**Project structure**

I have three projects

- "web": ASP.NET Core 2.0 project
- "LibA": .NET Standard 2.0 class library
- "LibB": .Net Standard 2.0 class library

LibA is referenced from web (by DLL reference). LibB is referenced by LibA (by project reference, since LibA and LibB are in the same VS2017 solution).

In practice there are more projects and references, but I have reproduced the problem with this.

I publish the web project using a command in a docker build image:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
```

**Dependency issue**

By inspecting the docker image that is being built, the /app folder contains both LibA.dll and LibB.dll, because it has implicitly determined that it needs to include LibB.dll to make "web" work. So far so good.

However, when I try to run the docker container, I get this error, even though both DLLs are in the same folder as the web application /app:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'LibB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On the other hand, if I explicitly reference both LibA and LibB from web, I can run the project without the error.

Coming from a .NET Framework world, it should normally be enough that the assemblies are in the same folder, but apparently I need to do something else to make dependencies of dependencies work?

**Project files**

web:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="LibA">
      <HintPath>..\lib\LibA.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

LibA:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LibB\ClassLibraryB.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

LibB:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but faced two issues: 

) When LibA is referenced from Web as direct Assembly reference (`<Reference Include="LibA.dll"/>`), transitive dependency resolution is new to me. As far as I know/remember referencing a DLL will include the DLL and only this DLL. Only <ProjectReference> and <PackageReference> will include transitive dependencies also.

b) Publishing the sample web-application didn't include LibB in the published folder - just as I was expecting (see above).

Could you provide the .csproj files for LibA, LibB and web?

Comment: I edited my question to include the project files. I just tried to removed the obj/bin folders, do a clean build and "dotnet publish". The LibB.dll and LibB.pdb still shows up in the publish folder, but it is still not able to run.
Does it have something to do with the .deps.json files? I noticed that in the docker build, only LibA.dll is mentioned.
What are my alternatives? Can I make a "local file" NuGet package and reference it by filename? I don't want to add all my static dependencies as projects to the solution and I don't want to publish them publicly to NuGet.

Comment: Dropping in a comment as this was the first result in Google. If your main project is .Net Core 3.1 but you've created a .Net Standard 2.1 library to go with it you get this exact error (which took me a while to work out!). Downgrading to .Net Standard 2.0 fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to file an answer, since it exceeds the character limit of a comment.

I copied those project files but still am not able to reproduce the issue. Publishing the app won't include LibB.dll in the published output folder, only LibA.dll is present. But in my opinion this is the expected behavior for a direct assembly reference.

> Does it have something to do with the .deps.json files?

If you or your build pipeline don't manipulate deps.json it typically has no influence on those problems, since it gets generated. Nate McMaster has a nice [blog post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/) on this.

Your alternatives are:

- Reference LibB.dll also as a direct assembly reference or manually copy it to the build output via msbuild. This can be a solution if the dependency tree of your direct assembly references is quite flat.
- Build a NuGet package for LibA and either

  - Build up a private feed via AppVeyor, VSTS/TFS, MyGet or any other private feed provider
  - Build up a "feed" in a directory on your local machine and use this directory as an additional NuGet package source. Just select the directory where you put the LibA.nupkg via Visual Studio > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources. This is a solution if you're the only one working on the web application and ever will be.
- Reference LibA as a project reference, since project references support transitive dependency resolution